# Connect to multiple VPN with Cisco Client

Tags: vpn, connection, cisco-vpn

I use VPN Client version 5.0.05.0290 in Windows XP SP3. Is it possible to be connected to more than one VPN server at the same time?

For example, I have some batches running every 5 minutes that are using a VPN domain. I need to run another batch that need to be connected to another VPN domain.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would need a router supporting the IPsec protocal, some static routes defining subnets of each VPN connection.

The other option would be to include in your script logging into the different VPN domains over a time frame and carrying out the operation individually, It would have to run recursively but lets say the batch would run on each VPN domain every 5mins.

I'd go with the second, may make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.lizhao.com/2008/02/22/multiple-vpn-connections-at-the-same-time seems like that's what you're looking for?